# Spreadsheet software that can open several CSV as tabs in the same window?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, office, csv, spreadsheet

I have 3 local CSV files that I often need to check.
I don't like to have too many windows open, so tabs would be great.

Is there a spreadsheet program that would open the 3 CSV files as tabs of the same window?

Requirements:

- Works on Ubuntu Linux
- Free
- Can open several CSV files from command line and show them in the same window
- Preferably lightweight, like Gnumeric
- No particular spreadsheet features needed except search, and copy (for pasting excerpts into Google Docs)

Comment: csv is just a text format, so are you open (ha) to opening them in a text editor rather than a spreadsheet type display? Notepad++ or Sublime (or probably half the other text editors on the planet) can easily do all of those.

Comment: @NickWilde: That would work except for the 5th requirement: I need to copy/paste, for instance 30 cells of the R column. Very hard to do with a text editor.

Comment: ah yes I wasn't thinking of columnar copy/past only row based. Definitely that would be hideous.

Comment: Use KDE with its KWin window manager. That has the ability to put arbitrary windows together into tab groups.

Comment: Regarding copy/paste, [Geany](http://www.geany.org/) allows you to select rectangles (columns) of text if you hold down Ctrl and Alt

Answer (score 1):

If it's really just the copying and pasting you need, and viewing side-by-side, there's no GUI programme I'm aware of (unfortunately, I have to do the same as you rather frequently). However, I've found just the standard system utilities do what I need. I use the following in Terminator (a split window terminal emulator):

```
column -s, -t < a.csv | less -#2 -N -S
```

To install terminator:

```
sudo aptitude install terminator
```

or

```
sudo yum install terminator
```

Copying and pasting into spreadsheets works just fine on LibreOffice and OpenOffice, but I'm not sure about Google Docs unfortunately, but I can only imagine it would work in a similar fashion.

Edit:

Sorry, I just realised it's columns rather than rows you're after, in which case the shortest command would likely be:

```
ruby -rcsv -e 'CSV.foreach(ARGV.shift) {|row| puts row[5]}' a.csv
```

Where `5` is the column you're after.